# HTTPS version of page throws 404, regular HTTP appears fine?

Tags: iis, php, ssl, http-status-code-404

I'm having a strange issue with a website in IIS on Windows Server 2003. It has a valid wild card certificate on it, however when I use HTTPS on the page I get a 404 not found. Without HTTPS it shows up fine. Also, if I go to the domain root of the site using HTTP the homepage shows up, but with HTTPS it REDIRECTS ME to a totally different website installed on the same IIS server. I am quite confused. I tried giving each site a unique IP address but it didn't change anything, I also tried changing the SSL ports, no luck. This IIS is setup to run PHP also. What could I check to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually what I do with SSL-enabled sites is assign them the required dedicated IP address, and then set all of the hostnames/domains to that IP.  Within IIS, set the website entry to use that IP address only with no hostnames specified (and ensure the SSL port is bound to the same IP as well).  Here's a screen capture for how the settings would look for IIS6:

[SSL Settings http://www.tlson.com/assets/content/screencaps/2010-06-07_1135.png](http://www.tlson.com/assets/content/screencaps/2010-06-07_1135.png)

Usually if you have different results for non-SSL vs. SSL it means that the SSL entry for the IP address that the domain points to is bound to a different website entry within IIS.  Double-check that the IP is assigned to the same entry in IIS all around.